# What is wrong with my code in determining palindrome in scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am trying to detect the palindrome lists in scheme. Here is my code:

```
;- Input : Takes only one parameter named inSeq
;- Output : It returns the reverse of inSeq if inSeq is a sequence.
; Otherwise it produces an error.
;- Examples :
; (reverse-sequence '(a b c)) --> evaluates to (c b a)
; (reverse-sequence '()) -------> evaluates to ()
(define reverse-sequence
 (lambda (inSeq)
   (if (sequence? inSeq)
       (if (null? inSeq) 
           inSeq 
           (append (reverse-sequence (cdr inSeq))
                   (list (car inSeq)))))))

;- Input : Takes only one parameter named inSeq
;- Output : It returns true if inSeq is a sequence and it is a palindrome.
; It returns false if inSeq is a sequence but not a plaindrome.
; Otherwise it gives an error.
;- Examples :
; (palindrome? '(a b a)) --> evaluates to true
; (palindrome? '()) -------> evaluates to true
; (palindrome? '(a 1 a)) --> produces an error
(define palindrome
 (lambda (inSeq)
   (if (sequence? inSeq) 
       (if (equal? reverse-sequence(inSeq) inSeq ) 
           #t 
           #f))))
```

When i try the input '(a b a) i get the following error:

```
The object (a b a) is not applicable
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

```
(equal? reverse-sequence(inSeq) inSeq )
```

which tries to call `(inSeq)` as a function of no arguments. It should read:

```
(equal? (reverse-sequence inSeq) inSeq )
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember, in Scheme the correct way to invoke procedure `f` on argument `x` is: `(f x)`. That explains why this snippet doesn't work:

```
reverse-sequence(inSeq)
```

It should have been:

```
(reverse-sequence inSeq)
```

Be aware that you'll run into trouble if the argument received isn't a *sequence*, you'll get a *void* value and you won't get a correct answer. Also, you could have used the built-in `reverse` procedure, but I guess you want to implement it yourself - with that in mind, it'd be a better idea to reverse the list accumulating the result in a parameter (tail recursion), so you don't have to `append` the results (which is expensive), just `cons` the results (which is very cheap). This is what I mean:

```
(define (reverse-sequence inSeq)
  (if (not (sequence? inSeq))
      '()  ; can't reverse if it's not a sequence
      (let loop ((inSeq inSeq)
                 (reversed '()))
        (if (null? inSeq)
            reversed
            (loop (cdr inSeq) (cons (car inSeq) reversed))))))

(define (palindrome inSeq)
  (if (not (sequence? inSeq))
      #f
      (equal? inSeq (reverse-sequence inSeq))))
```

Comment: Thanks, i think i could not get used to functional programming afer oo programming :)